# Hover appearing in the wrong position

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, drag-and-drop, hover

I have created a drag and drop list using AngularJS and the plugin "drag-and-drop-lists", but for some reason, when I move some item, it hovers a wrong item.

If I move the mouse over the item with the wrong hover, the hover disappear.

Does anyone know why it is occurring?

**JSFIDDLE**: https://jsfiddle.net/83gbS/60/

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-app="DemoApp">
    <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
        <ul dnd-list="categories" class="categories">
            <li
                ng-repeat="category in categories"
                dnd-draggable="category"
                dnd-droppable-in=".categories"
                dnd-effect-allowed="move"
                dnd-moved="categories.splice($index, 1)"
            >
                {{ category.name }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript/AngularJS**:

```
angular
    .module(
        'DemoApp',
        [ 'dndLists' ]
    )
    .controller(
        'DemoCtrl',
        function($scope) {
            $scope.categories = [
                {
                    name: "Category 1"

                },
                {
                    name: "Category 2"
                },
                {
                    name: "Category 3",

                },
                {
                    name: "Category 4"

                },
                {
                    name: "Category 5"
                },
                {
                    name: "Category 6",

                }
            ];
        }
    );
```

**CSS**:

```
ul[dnd-list] * { 
    pointer-events: none; 
}

ul[dnd-list], ul[dnd-list] > li { 
    pointer-events: auto;
    position: relative;
}

ul[dnd-list] {
    min-height: 42px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

ul[dnd-list] .dndDraggingSource {
    display: none;
}

ul[dnd-list] .dndPlaceholder {
    display: block;
    background-color: #ddd;
    min-height: 42px;
}

ul[dnd-list] li {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul[dnd-list] li.selected {
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    color: #3c763d;
}
ul[dnd-list] li:active{
    background:pink;
}
ul[dnd-list] li:hover{
    background:yellow;
}
```

**GIF EXAMPLE**:

[image]

Comment: It seems to be working as expected in Chrome, and IE9-11. Are you having trouble in a different browser?

Comment: No, I'm using Chrome latest version on Linux and the error persists. However, I've tested with Firefox and there the problem is not occuring. Very weird.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know you're not alone. It looks like there's an active undocumented bug in Chrome where the current mouse position used to trigger hover events is stored incorrectly and not updated throughout drag events.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is some bug with chrome and drag-events (possibly a linux exclusive bug). Seems like chrome detects hover on the position where the cursor started the drag as opposed to where the cursor is currently located.

My solution was to turn off pointer events from badly behaved elements inside dragstart:

```
// Add this code inside of the dragstart event handler 
badElem.style.pointerEvents="none"
```

Then in the dragend handler, we hook up a parentElement of our badly behaved elements with a onmousemove event that re-enables pointer events for the badly behaved elements:

```
// Add this code inside of the dragend event handler 
parentOfBadElems.onmousemove=()=>{
  badElem.style.pointerEvents="all"
}
```

This effectively disables incorrect hovers by via locking elements from being hovered at all until a user has completed their drag and moved their mouse.